# Call Javascript Function after Facebook API call has finished executing Graph API[2.5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook Graph API's ***send message*** feature in my web app. I want to show a pop up success dialog after the user has clicked on the send button of the dialog box rendered by Facebook API but currently it's being displayed at the same time as the Facebook rendered dialog box.

**JavaScript Code**..

```
     function importfb(){
        reasonForAddFriend = "importFacebook";

        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle the response

            // check whether user is logged in or not and ask for credentials if not.
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,locale,gender', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name+" "+response.id+" "+response.email);
                loginpassword = response.id;
                loginemail =  response.email;
            });

            // send message to facebook friends using send request dialog
            FB.ui({
                method: 'send',
                link: 'http://www.google.com/',
            });
        }, {scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends'});


        confirmationIndex("Success","importfb called");
    }
```

**Output of Current Code**..

[image: send message fb api]

I want the success dialog box to be displayed after I click the send button in the above screen shot not at the same time..Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at the relevant documentation for an API. `FB.ui` takes a second argument, a function that will be called when the dialog is closed.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui#parameters
>
> function(response)
>
> This specifies the function that is called
>   whenever the UI dialog is closed, either by success, cancellation, or
>   errors. The response object will depend on the dialog being used.
>   Consult the relevant dialog's own reference doc to see the response
>   object that should be returned. Defaults to null.

So simply pass a callback function and call your dialog there

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    link: 'http://www.google.com/',
},function(response){
    //check 'response' to see if call was successful
    confirmationIndex("Success","importfb called");
});
```

Comment: This code works thanks..Actually the Documentation of send dialog here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog said that this dialog has no response that's why didn't try the response function..

Comment: @Lucy, oh that just means `response` in the callback will not hold anything (meaning it will be `null`, `undefined`, or similar)